# Submenu with Astra Theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using Astra theme in wordpress and having problem displaying my submenu items in one line. The theme editor has so many files regarding css and I have tried all sorts of code. Even removed the word-break property from the existing code but nothing seems to be working.
This is the URL: http://www.marmarasasist.com/

I can't figure out where exactly to go and what change should I be making.

Answer (score 0):

just, go to this file - [frontend.min.css](http://www.marmarasasist.com/wp-content/themes/astra/assets/css/minified/frontend.min.css?ver=3.2.0)

remove `white-space: nowrap;` and `min-width: 250px;`

```
.main-navigation ul ul li {
  width: 100%;
}
```